# How to construct a matrix given column and null spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

The problem says: If possible, construct a matrix whose column space contains [1 1 0] and [0 1 1] and whose null space contains [1 0 1] and [0,0,1].

I know that the column space has to be part of the matrix, and I've managed to make two different matrices that each contain one of the null spaces with a simple system of equations, but I don't know how to go about finding both. So I'm stuck here:

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & ?\\1 & 1& ?\\0&1 & ?\end{bmatrix}

Or, if its not possible, could I get an explanation?

Comment: The condition on the column space implies the matrix has three rows and rank (at least) two. The condition on the null space implies the matrix has three columns and nullity (at least) two. So it's a $3\times3$ matrix, with rank plus nullity equal to four. That's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702230/how-to-construct-a-matrix-given-column-and-null-spaces/4702238#comment9952737_4702230), it's not possible. Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix that satisfied these constraints. Then:

- Since $[1, 1, 0] \in \textsf{Col}(A)$, we know that $m = 3$.
- Since $[1, 1, 0]$ and $[0, 1, 1]$ are linearly independent, we know that $\textsf{dim}(\textsf{Col}(A)) \geq 2$.
- Since $[1, 0, 1] \in \textsf{Null}(A)$, we know that $n = 3$.
- Since $[1, 0, 1]$ and $[0, 0, 1]$ are linearly independent, we know that $\textsf{dim}(\textsf{Null}(A)) \geq 2$.

So by the rank-nullity theorem:
\begin{align*}
3 &= n \\
&= \textsf{dim}(\textsf{Col}(A)) + \textsf{dim}(\textsf{Null}(A)) \\
&\geq 2 + 2 \\
&= 4
\end{align*}
a contradiction.